# Perl problems with Crypt::CBC based in Java code

Tags: java, perl, encryption, aes

I have java code that uses AES/CBC, And I need to rewrite in perl. My  goal is to reproduce the same result in both codes. Is it possible?

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class GenPass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String secret = "secret"; /* same secret */
        String password = args[0];
        if (args.length > 1) {
            secret = args[1];
        }
        System.out.println("Using secret: [" + secret + "]");
        System.out.println("Password [" + password + "]");
        String encodePassword = new GenPass().encodePassword(password, secret);
        System.out.println("Encoded password [" + encodePassword + "]");
    }

    private String encodePassword(String password, String secret) {
        try {
            final SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(this.decodeHex(secret.toCharArray()), "AES"); /* same set*/
            final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding"); // same set here

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));

            String paddedString = StringUtils.left(StringUtils.rightPad(password, 16, (char) 0), 16);

            byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(paddedString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedBytes);

        } catch (InvalidKeyException invalidKeyException) {
            System.out.println("Chave incorreta durante criptografia da senha" + invalidKeyException);
            throw new RuntimeException(invalidKeyException);

        } catch (GeneralSecurityException generalSecurityException) {
            System.out.println("Falha inesperada durante criptografia da senha" + generalSecurityException.toString());
            throw new RuntimeException(generalSecurityException);
        }

    }

    private String normalize(String password) {
        char[] array = new char[16];
        char[] temp = password.toCharArray();
        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, array, 0, 16);
        return String.valueOf(array);
    }

    public static byte[] decodeHex(final char[] data) {

        final int len = data.length;

        if ((len & 0x01) != 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Odd number of characters.");
        }

        final byte[] out = new byte[len >> 1];

        // two characters form the hex value.
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < len; i++) {
            int f = toDigit(data[j], j) << 4;
            j++;
            f = f | toDigit(data[j], j);
            j++;
            out[i] = (byte) (f & 0xFF);
        }

        return out;
    }

    protected static int toDigit(final char ch, final int index) {
        final int digit = Character.digit(ch, 16);
        if (digit == -1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Illegal hexadecimal character " + ch + " at index " + index);
        }
        return digit;
    }
}
```

The result isn't same. I can't figure out where is the mistake...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

use Crypt::CBC;
use MIME::Base64;
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);

my $plainText = "textsample";
my $iv = "                ";
my $key = "secret";

my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(
    -key         => $key,
    -iv          => $iv,
    -cipher      => 'OpenSSL::AES',
    -literal_key => 0,
    -header      => "none",
    -padding     => "null",
    -keysize     => 16
);

my $encrypted = $cipher->encrypt($plainText);
my $base64 = encode_base64($encrypted);

chomp $base64;
print("The '$plainText' encrypted is '$base64'\n");
```

Comment: You should start by creating a set number of test cases from your Java code, and write unit tests for your Perl code with these. Then add those test cases here, so we have something more to work with.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed, the problem was with -iv parameter.

```
my $iv = ("\x0") x 16;
```